# Spring - OrderBy relation attribute using CriteriaQuery (Specification) ignores the rows which does not have the relation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to order by a relation attribute, I am using `toPredicat` (Jpa `Specification`, SpringBoot framework) to generate the query.

I am getting the right order but **the problem is that the rows that does not have this relation (the relation is null) is been removed from the result set**.

Below is an example: 
let's say we have two entity, `Email` which **may have a** `Document`.
I want to order the `Emails` using the `Document.name` (the attribute **name** of `Document`)

So i have my specification:

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import javax.persistence.criteria.*;


public class EmailSpecification implements Specification<Email> {


    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Email> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if (xx) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(yy);
        }

        //...

        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(
                        root.get('document').get('name'));



        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))
    }
}
```

and when i Call

```
List<Email> result = emailRepository.findAll(new EmailSpecification());
```

**I have a list of emails with the right order but with only the email that have a document ( I want all the email even if it does not have a document)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should need a Left join for that, maybe something like:

```
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(
                        root.join("document", JoinType.LEFT).get("name"));
```